# Resize and center dynamic content inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to resize and center dynamic content inside a div onLoad and on window resize to suit my liquid layout.

Posting a link `< http://jsfiddle.net/h52tqaz2/">fJSFiddle >` due to easy understanding.

Why doesn't it center all DIVs onLoad (but it centers when resize)?
How can I make this scale according to the height of the window as well as according to the width of the window by maintaing its aspect-ratio?

NOTE: The dynamic content are not the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ready` instead of `onload` :

```
$(document).ready(center_images);
$(window).resize(center_images);

function center_images() {
    var parent_width = $('.container').width();
    $('.content').each(function() {
        var content_width = $(this).width();
        var margin = (parent_width-content_width)/2;
        $(this).css('left', margin);
    });
}
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h52tqaz2/2/)**

Comment: Thanks. Nice clean-up. Any idea how to maintaing the aspect-ratio while resizing the window? The code scales contents horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: @JonaNathali: i'm not sure what do you mean `maintaing the aspect-ratio while resizing the window` but i think your question has been answered and you are asking another question.